# how to call react handler manually from another javascript file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to call react handler manually from another javascript file?

```
import './external/myPlugin'
class Title extends Component {
    @autobind
    setTitle(e) {
        // do something
    }

    render() {
        return (<Textarea className="parent" value="default" onChange={this.setTitle} />);
    }
}
```

// here is the just normal javascript file. (It will be opened by window.open)

```
var titleElement = window.opener.document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0]
titleElement.value = "this is the new title";
```

how to call 'handleChangeTitle' function?

// I tried this. but It doesn't work...

```
titleElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true}));
titleElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true}));
titleElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('textarea', { bubbles: true}));
```

Comment: There is no function called `handleChangeTitle` in your code at all...

Comment: Obviously, if you can, you want to avoid doing that. :-) FWIW, I can confirm that the above doesn't work with a DOM `textarea` (no idea what `Textarea` is in the above, but it likely has the same issue): https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/n86e0wrp/1/ DOM handlers get triggered, but not the React one.

Comment: Yeah, React handles events via wrappers of some sort, so that won't work. Anyway, @kokojustin, what're you trying to actually achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, if you have any choice, find a different way to solve the underlying problem that doesn't require triggering the event handler externally. :-)

The only way I've found is to hook into the DOM event and forward it to `setTitle`. Here's an example (see `***` comments primarily):

```js
class Title extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: ""
        };
        // *** A ref so we can access the DOM element
        this.titleRef = React.createRef();
        this.setTitle = this.setTitle.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // ** Hook the input event on the DOM element
        if (this.titleRef.current) {
            this.titleRef.current.addEventListener("input", this.setTitle);
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // *** Release the input event on the DOM element
        if (this.titleRef.current) {
            this.titleRef.current.removeEventListener("input", this.setTitle);
        }
    }

    setTitle({target: {value: title}}) {
        // *** Update the title. Note that if the user types in the element and React
        // fires its event, you'll get two events (one from React, another from the DOM).
        // If you need to do something other than setting state in this method, check
        // first to see if the new title and the old are identical. But there's no need
        // if you're just calling `setState`, it will ignore an unnecessary state change.
        console.log(`setTitle: ${e.target.value}`);
        this.setState({title: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        // *** Use the current title as the value, use the ref
        const {title} = this.state;
        return (<textarea id="example" ref={this.titleRef} className="parent" value={title} onChange={this.setTitle} />);
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<Title/>, document.getElementById("root"));

setTimeout(function() {
    const example = document.getElementById("example");
    example.value = "updated";
    example.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true}));
    example.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true}));
}, 800);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Again, though, if you can find a way to avoid needing to trigger the event handler externally in the first place, that's what I'd do.